# Finding the tangent space of a torus

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

## Problem: Find Basis for Tangent Space of Torus

Suppose I have a torus
$$
T^2 = \left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\, : \, \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + R^2 - r^2\right)^2 - 4R^2(x^2+ 
 y^2) = 0\right\}
$$
How do I find an orthonormal basis for its tangent space $T_x$ and for $T_x^{\perp}$?

## My Attempt

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08446.pdf) paper that one should basically first compute $Q$, the transpose of the Jacobian and then compute its QR decomposition to find the basis, so I tried this approach. Since the constraint defining the torus is $q:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ we know that the transpose of its Jacobian will be $3\times 1$ and given by
$$
Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_x q(x,y,z) \\
    \partial_y q(x,y,z) \\
    \partial_z q(x,y,z)
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    4x(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + R^2 - r^2) - 8xR^2 \\
    4y(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + R^2 - r^2) - 8yR^2 \\
    4z(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + R^2 - r^2)
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 1}
$$
Now, however, I don't end up with a matrix, but with a colum vector and I should be taking its QR decomposition to find the basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the case of a sphere sphere $S^2 = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - r^2 = 0\}$ easier to illustrate. As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040856/tangent-space-of-manifold-and-kernel/1041697), for all $p \in S^2$ we have $$T_p S^2 = \ker df_p,$$ where $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - r^2$. Explicitly, for $p = (a, b, c)$ we compute that
$$df_p = \begin{pmatrix} 2a & 2b & 2c  \end{pmatrix},$$
so we see that the kernel is
$$\ker df_p = \{v \in \mathbb R^3: \langle a, b, c \rangle^T \cdot v = 0  \}.$$ This set is no other than a plane with normal vector $\langle a, b, c \rangle$, which indeed is the tangent space to $S^2$ at $p$.

**Edit**: So, finding an ON basis for the tangent space amounts to finding an ON basis of the kernel of $df_p$. As the kernel is perpendicular to the *row space* of $df_p$, an ON basis of the normal space amounts to an ON basis of the row space of $df_p$. In this case $df_p$ has one row, so the vector $df_p^T$, once normalized, is your desired basis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still a bit confused. Once you've found the normal vector to the plane, in your example $(a,b,c)^\top$ do you need to use Gram-Schmidt on $(a,b,c)$ to find the plane?

Comment: Just edited the last part to explain more. Did it answer your question? Feel free to follow up.

Comment: Mmm I think I'm starting to understand, I will research those topics a bit more and then in case come back to you. Thank you so much! Does that mean that the basis for the torus at a point $(a, b, c)$ is given by $Q(a, b, c)$ ?

Comment: You're welcome. An ON basis to the tangent space is an ON basis of the kernel of the Jacobian is an ON basis of the column space of the transpose of the Jacobian.

Comment: Question: you say that $\langle a, b, c\rangle^\top \cdot v = 0$ is a plane with normal vector $p$. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point%E2%80%93normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane) I can see that the equation should be $(a,b,c)^\top\cdot(r - p) = 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The former is a plane with normal vector $\langle a, b, c \rangle$ that goes through the origin. The latter is a plane with normal $\langle a, b, c \rangle$ that goes through $p$.

Comment: Computationally, how would one go about finding the basis for that space? Could you give me a recipe that would work Sphere, Torus, etc

Comment: Wait surely $df_p^\top$ CANNOT be the basis for the tangent space. The tangent space will be $2D$ and will need two basis vectors. I know how to find them in the particular case of a sphere just using polar coordinates, but how do you find them in general for a manifold given by a constraint?

Comment: First, $df_p^\top$ is a basis for the normal space (which is one-dimensional for a surface in \mathbb{R}^3). Second, to find a basis of $\ker df_p$ you can use linear algebra (row reduce, choose free variables, etc.)